# Click event in node.js does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am using Node.js + Express + Jade + Socket.io to set up click events in one browser to trigger a click on a button in another. I am having difficulty getting this to work. The code I have so far is:

Client side (index.jade):

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  $('#buttonLeft').tap(function() {
    socket.emit('keyLeft');
  });
});
```

Server side:

```js
var sockets = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('keyLeft', function(){
    socket.broadcast.emit('keyLeft');
  });
});
```

Another client side (index.php):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider-style.css" />
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php
 $imagesTotal = 8;     // SET TOTAL IMAGES IN GALLERY
?>

<div class="galleryContainer">

  <div class="galleryPreviewContainer">
    <div class="galleryPreviewImage">
      <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesTotal; $i++) {
          echo '<img class="previewImage' . $i . '" src="images/image' . $i . '.jpg" width="900" height="auto" alt="" />';
        }
      ?>
  </div>

  <div class="galleryPreviewArrows">
    <a id="previousSlideArrow" href="#" class="previousSlideArrow">&lt;</a>
      <a id="nextSlideArrow" href="#" class="nextSlideArrow">&gt;</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// init variables
var imagesTotal = <?php echo $imagesTotal; ?>;
var currentImage = 1;
var thumbsTotalWidth = 0;

$('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).addClass("active");
$('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).addClass("active");
$('div.description' + currentImage).addClass("visible");

// PREVIOUS ARROW CODE
$('a.previousSlideArrow').click(function() {
 $('img.previewImage' + currentImage).hide();
 $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).removeClass("active");
 $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).removeClass("active");
 $('div.description' + currentImage).removeClass("visible");

 currentImage--;

 if (currentImage == 0) {
  currentImage = imagesTotal;
 }

 $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).addClass("active");
 $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).addClass("active");
 $('img.previewImage' + currentImage).show();
 $('div.description' + currentImage).addClass("visible");

 return false;
});
// ===================


// NEXT ARROW CODE
$('a.nextSlideArrow').click(function() {
 $('img.previewImage' + currentImage).hide();
 $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).removeClass("active");
 $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).removeClass("active");
 $('div.description' + currentImage).removeClass("visible");

 currentImage++;

 if (currentImage == imagesTotal + 1) {
  currentImage = 1;
 }

 $('a.galleryBullet' + currentImage).addClass("active");
 $('a.thumbnailsimage' + currentImage).addClass("active");
 $('img.previewImage' + currentImage).show();
 $('div.description' + currentImage).addClass("visible");

 return false;
});
// ===================
</script>

<script src="http://mojoer.kr:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="slide-script.js></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks~

Comment: so you have two `io.connect` in the client side, is that right?

Comment: what does "having difficulty getting this to work" mean? give us details please

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande yes, you are right. I have io.connect in both clients.

Comment: @mk12ok I tried to implement another event such as scrolling event and it worked well, but when I tried the code for click event (those above), it did not work as I want it to (trigger click in another client file). I am not sure if either my code is not right or I miss something in my code.

Comment: You should only have one io.connect, that's why you're not getting anything in `socket.on('keyLeft'` on the client side.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I tried to remove the io.connect from the first client (index.jade), but it still does not work :(

Comment: as far as I can understand your express server renders index.jade.. but how do you open index.html?

Comment: @mk12ok ah it is inside another web hosting server.

Comment: does the second client receive 'keyLeft' event? you may add some `console.log('keyLeft received')` to check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your setup with the following code:

server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('left', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit('leftButtonClicked');
    });
     socket.on('right', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit('rightButtonClicked');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

jade client:

```
doctype html
html
  body
    h1 Testing socket.io
    h3(id="status") not connected 
    buttons
      button#leftButton Prev
      button#rightButton Next
    br  
    h3 actions:
    p#actions
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script.
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "connected";   
      });
      document.getElementById("leftButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
        socket.emit('left');
        document.getElementById("actions").innerHTML += "Prev button click sent<br>";
      });
      document.getElementById("rightButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
        socket.emit('right');
        document.getElementById("actions").innerHTML += "Next button click sent<br>";
      });
```

html gallery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
        <div id="preview" style="padding: 5px;"></div>   
        <div id="fullSize" class="fullgalleryPreviewImage" style="padding: 5px;"></div>   
        <div style="padding: 5px;">
            <button id="previousSlideArrow" style="height: 4em; width=100px;">&lt;</button>
            <button id="nextSlideArrow" style="height: 4em; width=100px;">&gt;</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // init variables
      var imagesTotal = 8;
      var currentImage = 1;

      for (var i = 1; i <= imagesTotal; i++) {
          document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML += '<img class="previewImage' + i + '"src="images/image' + i +         '.jpg" + width="200" height="auto" style="margin-left: 2px;" />';
      }     

      document.getElementById('fullSize').innerHTML = '<img src="images/image' + currentImage + '.jpg" + width="800" height="auto" />';

      // PREVIOUS ARROW CODE
      document.getElementById('previousSlideArrow').addEventListener('click', function () {
          currentImage--;
          if (currentImage === 0) {
              currentImage = imagesTotal;
          }
          document.getElementById('fullSize').innerHTML = '<img src="images/image' + currentImage + '.jpg" + width="800" height="auto" />';
      });

      // NEXT ARROW CODE
      document.getElementById('nextSlideArrow').addEventListener('click', function () {
          currentImage++;
          if (currentImage === imagesTotal + 1) {
              currentImage = 1;
          }
          document.getElementById('fullSize').innerHTML = '<img src="images/image' + currentImage + '.jpg" + width="800" height="auto" />';
      });

      // socket.io
      var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
      socket.on('connect', function () {
          console.log('connected');
      }); 
      socket.on('leftButtonClicked', function () {
          document.getElementById('previousSlideArrow').click();
      }); 
      socket.on('rightButtonClicked', function () {
          document.getElementById('nextSlideArrow').click();
      }); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works - when you click buttons in the jade client you can browse the gallery in the html client. 
Please move the socket.io loader `<script src="http://mojoer.kr:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to the `<head>` section - if you have it at the end of the `<body>` it is not loaded yet when you execute `var socket = io(<server address>);` and you should see the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` in your browser's console.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried adding document.getElementById("actions").innerHTML += "button click sent" to see the connection and now both clients are connected to socket.io <script src="http://mojoer.kr:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> (before it was not). The jade client works well and it can send the click request, however the html client does not receive the request.

Comment: can you show me the entire code of the html client?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I understand the concept now. It works locally, but I have one question, if the server sets the jade client (app) to listen to other port than the socket.io port, for example app.listen(8000) and socket.io listen(8080), how to connect the html client which is on different web server with socket.io? I tried with <script src="http://mojoer.kr:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"> and var socket = io(<"http://mojoer.kr:8080">) on both of jade and html client, but still the html client didn't receive any request from the jade client.

Comment: the server listens on some port: `http.listen(<some port>);` and both clients have to connect to exactly the same port: jade client connects with `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")` and then `var socket = io();` and the html client connects with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>` (in the head section!) and then `var socket = io("http://mojoer.kr:<some port>");`